# Kendo Datepicker not working in ASP.NET.MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Instead of datepicker, normal text input is showing on the browser.

Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker"))
```

Here screenshot of browser:

[image]

[image]

Console Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).kendoDateTimePicker is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Index:58)
at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3174)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:447)
at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.10.2.js:118)
```

Comment: Is there another contol on the page with Id as "datepicker"

Comment: Any scripting errors in the console?

Comment: @SteveGreene... thanks...yes one error it is showing in the console...I update my question, please have a look.

Comment: Are you sure you are including the kendo javascript file(i.e. kendo.all.min.js) in your page.  That is the exact error you will get if it is missing.

Comment: Here are the steps for [Kendo MVC Bundling](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/asp-net-mvc-5)